# how to encode user values for database to utf-8 using C#

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, web

I have this asp.net project and I want to recieve data from the user in a different language (Hebrew). For that matter, I understand that working with Hebrew chars requires a utf-8 encoding.

I need to get the data (post method) and store it into my database. How do I do that without risking getting "??????????" string instead of the data?

thanks in advance!

Comment: do you need the data to be human ledgible in the database?

Comment: What does the string look like when you reveice the post data in your asp.net project? How do you insert that string into the database?

Comment: Where are you seeing the "?????????" characters -- in the post data or after it is posted to the database? IIRC, varchar/char don't support a wide charset so you may need to use nvarchar/nchar (assuming SQL Server here).

Comment: @user2396866 - This would depend on the type of database you have What has your research shown you on how to store UTF-8 encoded strings in a database?

Answer (score 1):

> For that matter, I understand that working with Hebrew chars requires a utf-8 encoding.

No, not particularly. It requires *something* that supports Unicode (or at least, that's the simplest way of working) but you shouldn't need to perform the encoding yourself.

You have two potential problems:

- Getting the data correctly from the request
- Propagating it correctly to the database

Tackle them separately. The latter task should be easy - so long as you make sure your database is set up to support Unicode, you should be able to use an `nvarchar` field and just propagate the value as a string. You shouldn't be trying to encode it yourself.

I suggest you get that working with a small console app first, specifying a string literal with some Hebrew text in (perhaps using the `\uxxxx` escaping to make *absolutely sure* that you've got the data correctly). Insert it, then fetch it back, dumping the string character-by-character, casting each character to `int` to ensure that you see the actual Unicode value.

Once you're confident in the database part, you can work on the web app part. If it doesn't work initially, log all the data you receive, again making sure you log each `char` as an integer so you can see *exactly* what you've got without any risk of the logs being in the wrong encoding.

Comment: Thanks you for your quick answer!
But I wonder - is there any other way of getting Hebrew data in C# correctly without all of that work?

Comment: @user2396866: "All that work" is really just diagnostics if things go wrong. The actual production code should be very straightforward - if everything works, you *should* just be able to take the string from the request and put it straight into the database. You do need to make sure that your database (and the fields) are correctly set up to be able to handle full Unicode, but that's all.